# HTML form input tag name element array with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, input

This is a two part question.  Someone answered a similar question the other day (which also contained info about this type of array in PHP), but I cannot find it.

1.) First off, what is the correct terminology for an array created on the end of the name element of an input tag in a form?

```
<form>

    <input name="p_id[]" value="0"/>
    <input name="p_id[]" value="1"/>
    <input name="p_id[]" value="2"/>

</form>
```

2.) How do I get the information from that array with JavaScript? Specifically, I am right now just wanting to count the elements of the array.  Here is what I did but it isn't working.

```
function form_check(){
    for(var i = 0; i < count(document.form.p_id[]); i++){  //Error on this line

        if (document.form.p_name[i].value == ''){
            window.alert('Name Message');
            document.form.p_name[i].focus();
            break;
        }

        else{
            if (document.form.p_price[i].value == ''){
                window.alert('Price Message');
                document.form.p_price[i].focus();
                break;
            }

            else{
                update_confirmation();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

> 1.) First off, what is the correct terminology for an array created on the end of the name element of an input tag in a form?

"Oftimes Confusing PHPism"

As far as JavaScript is concerned a bunch of form controls with the same name are just a bunch of form controls with the same name, and form controls with names that include square brackets are just form controls with names that include square brackets.

The PHP naming convention for form controls with the same name is sometimes useful (when you have a number of groups of controls so you can do things like this:

```
<input name="name[1]">
<input name="email[1]">
<input name="sex[1]" type="radio" value="m">
<input name="sex[1]" type="radio" value="f">

<input name="name[2]">
<input name="email[2]">
<input name="sex[2]" type="radio" value="m">
<input name="sex[2]" type="radio" value="f">
```

) but does confuse some people. Some other languages have adopted the convention since this was originally written, but generally only as an optional feature. For example, via [this module for JavaScript](https://www.npmjs.com/package/qs#readme).

> 2.) How do I get the information from that array with JavaScript?

It is still just a matter of getting the property with the same name as the form control from `elements`. The trick is that since the name of the form controls includes square brackets,  you can't use [dot notation and have to use square bracket notation](http://www.dev-archive.net/articles/js-dot-notation/) just like any other [JavaScript property name that includes special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953704/how-to-access-object-properties-containing-special-characters).

Since you have multiple elements with that name, it will be a collection rather then a single control, so you can loop over it with a standard for loop that makes use of its length property.

```
var myForm = document.forms.id_of_form;
var myControls = myForm.elements['p_id[]'];
for (var i = 0; i < myControls.length; i++) {
    var aControl = myControls[i];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for.  I modified it a little though... `for(i = 0; i < document.form.elements['p_id[]'].length; i++)`

Comment: Using `i` as a global isn't a good idea (it is just asking for scoping issues to bite you, either now or in the future because you have got into bad habits). Using `document.form` is bad practice because (a) the `document.forms` collection will make it clearer what you are doing and `form` isn't a very detailed name (and `document.form` could be confused with `document.forms` which makes maintenance more confusing. Scrunching things up on to a single line is fine though, I was just more explicit so you could see what is going on.

Comment: @Quentin: `for (var i...)` is in fact the same as `var i; for (i ...)` because [JavaScript variables are function scoped](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html), not block-scoped as is the case in many popular OO-languages.

Comment: @Laoujin — typoknig didn't say `var i; for (i ...)` though.

Answer (score 10):

Try this something like this:

```
var p_ids = document.forms[0].elements["p_id[]"];
alert(p_ids.length);
for (var i = 0, len = p_ids.length; i < len; i++) {
  alert(p_ids[i].value);
}
```

Comment: I have a problem when the form element is drop-down list. Can you give me solution for my question in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58994834/capture-selected-values-from-dynamic-drop-down-lists-using-javascript

Answer (score 4):

`document.form.p_id.length` ... not count().

You really should give your form an id

```
<form id="myform">
```

Then refer to it using:

```
var theForm = document.getElementById("myform");
```

Then refer to the elements like:

```
for(var i = 0; i < theForm.p_id.length; i++){
```

Answer (score 3):

To answer your questions in order: 
   1) There is no specific name for this.  It's simply multiple elements with the same name (and in this case type as well).  Name isn't unique, which is why id was invented (it's supposed to be unique).
  2)

```
function getElementsByTagAndName(tag, name) {
    //you could pass in the starting element which would make this faster
    var elem = document.getElementsByTagName(tag);  
    var arr = new Array();
    var i = 0;
    var iarr = 0;
    var att;
    for(; i < elem.length; i++) {
        att = elem[i].getAttribute("name");
        if(att == name) {
            arr[iarr] = elem[i];
            iarr++;
        }
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: Wow. That's just ugly. Using `new Array()` instead of `[]`, keeping a length tracker instead of using `arr.length` or `arr.push()`, initializing `i` outside the for loop, using `getAttribute` instead of just going for the name property, working globally instead of within a form, and all the get (more or less) the same results of `document.forms.element.elements_name`. (Oh and `getElementsByName` could have been used too).

Answer (score -3):

Here’s some PHP and JavaScript demonstration code that shows a simple way to create indexed fields on a form (fields that have the same name) and then process them in both JavaScript and PHP. The fields must have both "ID" names and "NAME" names. Javascript uses the ID and PHP uses the NAME.

```
<?php
// How to use same field name multiple times on form
// Process these fields in Javascript and PHP
// Must use "ID" in Javascript and "NAME" in PHP 
echo "<HTML>";
echo "<HEAD>";
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
function TestForm(form) {
// Loop through the HTML form field (TheId) that is returned as an array. 
// The form field has multiple (n) occurrences on the form, each which has the same name.
// This results in the return of an array of elements indexed from 0 to n-1.
// Use ID  in Javascript
var i = 0;
document.write("<P>Javascript responding to your button click:</P>");
for (i=0; i < form.TheId.length; i++) {
  document.write(form.TheId[i].value);
  document.write("<br>");
}  
}
</script>
<?php
echo "</HEAD>";
echo "<BODY>";
$DQ = '"';  # Constant for building string with double quotes in it.

if (isset($_POST["MyButton"])) {
  $TheNameArray = $_POST["TheName"];  # Use NAME in PHP
  echo "<P>Here are the names you submitted to server:</P>";
  for ($i = 0; $i <3; $i++) {   
    echo $TheNameArray[$i] . "<BR>";
  } 
}
echo "<P>Enter names and submit to server or Javascript</P>";
echo "<FORM NAME=TstForm METHOD=POST ACTION=" ;
echo $DQ . "TestArrayFormToJavascript2.php" . $DQ . "OnReset=" . $DQ . "return allowreset(this)" . $DQ . ">";
echo "<FORM>";
echo "<INPUT ID = TheId NAME=" . $DQ . "TheName[]" . $DQ . " VALUE=" . $DQ . "" . $DQ . ">";
echo "<INPUT ID = TheId NAME=" . $DQ . "TheName[]" . $DQ . " VALUE=" . $DQ . "" . $DQ . ">";
echo "<INPUT ID = TheId NAME=" . $DQ . "TheName[]" . $DQ . " VALUE=" . $DQ . "" . $DQ . ">";
echo "<P><INPUT TYPE=submit NAME=MyButton VALUE=" . $DQ . "Submit to server"    . $DQ . "></P>";
echo "<P><BUTTON onclick=" . $DQ . "TestForm(this.form)" . $DQ . ">Submit to Javascript</BUTTON></P>"; 
echo "</FORM>";
echo "</BODY>";
echo "</HTML>";
```