# JQuery arrays from innerHTML objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, jquery-ui, array-initialization

Learning to code and having a problem creating arrays from jQuery objects. I would like to give the user the option of adding as many "Favorite Books" as they want to their profile.

The UI is written in jQuery,

```
<script language="javascript">
    function one()
    {
        var i = 1;
        my.innerHTML = my.innerHTML +"<br><input type='text' name='title'+i[] >"
        var n = 1;
        [
        div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML +"<br><input type='text' name='author'+n[] >"
        ]
    }
</script>
```

I have tried:

```
var obj = $('input');
var arr = $.makeArray(obj);
```

I was hoping it was actually that easy but the output is:

```
<div id="div">
<br>
<input type="text" +n[]="" name="author">
<br>
<input type="text" +n[]="" name="author">
<br>
<input type="text" +n[]="" name="author">
</div>
```

I have tried option number two which I found here yet gave me the same output:

```
var author = new Array();

//get all the authors
$('.auth input').each(function (i)
{
    var author= $(this).val();

    if(author!= '')
    {
        author[author] = author;
        alert(author.length);
    }
});
```

and same results. I was hoping for results like this:

```
<div id="div">
<br>
<input type="text" name="author[0]">
<br>
<input type="text" name="author[1]">
<br>
<input type="text" name="author[2]">
</div>
```

so I can parse out to a PHP array.

Comment: Do you really need to store information in an array? :S

Comment: Ah! try something like `<input type='text' name='author[' + n + ']+' />`. I see a lot of possible typo here.. [See this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3234205/html-form-input-tag-name-element-array-with-javascript)

Comment: Thanks but it outputs
    <div id="my">
    <br>
    <input type="text" ']+'="" n="" +="" name="UnitID[">
    <br>
    <input type="text" ']+'="" n="" +="" name="UnitID[">
    <br>

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```
<script language="javascript">
    var i = 0;
    function one(){
       $('#my').append("<br><input type='text' name='title["+i+"]'>");
       $('#div').append("<br><input type='text' name='author["+i+"]'>");
       i++;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: the variables array[0] does not increment when executed. it just shoots  5 or 10 author[0].

Comment: AHA it worked when I put the Variable outside the function. Thanks Mihai