# How can I access object properties containing special characters?

Tags: javascript

I have a `form` DOM element:

```
var virDom = document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0];
```

`virDom` has two fields with IDs `creditId` and `pwdId..`. I can access `virDom.creditId`  without any issue, but `virDom.pwdId..` is failing with a syntax error, because of the periods contained in the name.

How can I access such properties?

Answer (score 62):

Use [**bracket notation**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation):

```
virDom['creditId']
virDom['pwdId..']
```

This applies to any object, and it is particularly useful for non-identifier-safe characters and also for accessing keys that you may not know ahead of time.

Answer (score 3):

For a nested object with a special character like below,

```
var details = {"name-details": {"first-name": "Kiran"}}
```

use

```
console.log(details["name-details"]["first-name"])
```

Comment: The syntax highlighting is weird for the "var details" line. Why? Can it be fixed?