# Adding new property to object

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript object which I use as type of map with key value pairs.

Population of this map occurs when value is injected to it from controller :

```
var people = {"2":"Brad","3":"Antonio","5":"Stacy","6":"Marry","1":"Jim"}
```

I want to create a new object but with one more entry i.e in pseudo code

```
var new_people = people + {11: "John"}
```

I tried to copy people to new people first and then :

```
new_people.\"11\" = "John"
```

and

```
new_people."11" = "John"
```

Both produce failure. While any string instead of number works i.e

```
new_people.anystring = "John"

var new_people = {"2":"Brad","3":"Antonio","5":"Stacy","6":"Marry","1":"Jim", "anystring":"John"}
```

Comment: It's not quite true that any string will work. `1string` is a string, but `new_people.1string` won't work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to access any element using javascript, if elemet is having special characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953704/how-to-access-any-element-using-javascript-if-elemet-is-having-special-characte) and [What is the most efficient way to clone a JavaScript object?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/122102/218196).

Comment: In your example `new_people.anystring = "John"`, `anystring` is a sequence of characters, but it is not a string in the sense of a JavaScript data type. It is an *identifier name*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use indexing:

```
new_people['11'] = 'John';
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to add a key value to the object:

```
people['11'] = "John";
```

If the key was a valid identifier name(not a number) you could have used this:

```
people.key = "John";
```

You have to use the indexes when it's not a valid variable name:

```
people["~!#$#$#HV"] ="some value";
```

Answer (score 2):

You will have a problem because variables hold references when storing objects.  By mutating new_people, you are also mutating people.

```
var people = {"1":"James"}
console.log(people);       // Object {1: "James"}
var new_people = people;
new_people["2"] = "Jimmy";
console.log(people);       // Object {1: "James", 2: "Jimmy"}
console.log(new_people);   // Object {1: "James", 2: "Jimmy"}
```

You'll need to clone the object first then mutate the clone so you don't affect the original object.

One easy way to do that is using the [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/#extend) extend() method like this:

```
var new_people = _.extend({}, people, {"2": "Jimmy"});
console.log(people);       // Object {1: "James"}
console.log(new_people);   // Object {1: "James", 2: "Jimmy"}
```

Or similarly, with [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) extend() like this:

```
var new_people = $.extend({}, people, {"2": "Jimmy"});
console.log(people);       // Object {1: "James"}
console.log(new_people);   // Object {1: "James", 2: "Jimmy"}
```

Comment: Yup: the line `var new_people = people + {11: "John"}` in the question doesn't create a new object. (It actually creates a string.)

Comment: @PaulD.Waite the OP indicated that `var new_people = people + {11: "John"}` was pseudo code.

Comment: @JeffShaver: ah, yes I see. Hadn't noticed that.

Answer (score 0):

@Gandalf StormCrow Here is a code: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f8gnj/)

```
var people = {"2":"Brad","3":"Antonio","5":"Stacy","6":"Marry","1":"Jim"};

var newpeople = {"11": "John"};
jQuery.extend(people, newpeople);
//Now: people = {"2":"Brad","3":"Antonio","5":"Stacy","6":"Marry","1":"Jim","11": "John"}

for(var i in people){
  alert(people[i]);  
};
```