# JSON call data array that has whitespaces in its name

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json

I'm calling a json string that has white spaces in the its identifiers which is causing my code to break. I'd like to call the first name and last name

```
var names = jQuery.parseJSON('[{"F name":"Chris1","Lname":"Test1"},
{"F name":"Chirs2 ","Lname":"Test2"},{"F name":"Chris3","Lname":"Test3"}]');

//This outputs **First Name: undefined** 
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=('First Name: '+names[1].Fname+'\n 
\n <br/>Last Name: '+names[1].Lname+'');

//This outputs nothing
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=('First Name: '+names[1].["F name"]+
'\n \n <br/>Last Name: '+names[1].Lname+'');
```

I know the naming sucks, and it should not have a space like "F name" but its not my original data so I have to use the naming convention. 
Do you know the correct syntax to  display the first name in this array?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to access object properties containing special characters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953704/how-to-access-object-properties-containing-special-characters)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be this:

```
names[1]["F name"]
```

Without the `.`