# javascript json uncaught syntaxerror unexpected token illegal

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am getting server response json with special character, How can i remove this special charecter from it. It tried replace() but its not working. My json sample is here

```
{
     "@tag":"1013170",
     "@title":"Holman Rd & Trestle Glen Rd",
     "@lat":"37.8067794",
     "@lon":"-122.2325773",
     "@stopId":"52750"
 }
```

Comment: where is the special character?

Comment: Its a valid JSON, You must have bug in some other place, check it at http://jsonlint.org/

Comment: Yes its a valid json. Yes i mean '@'

Comment: @MuhammadAamirALi check my solution is it helpful to you ???

Comment: @rajeshkakawat Thanks for your answer let me check

Comment: How are you trying to get the data? If you tell jQuery to expect JSONP, then you will get a syntax error if the server returns JSON. What you have posted so far is valid though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try something like this

```
    var str =   '{"@tag":"1013170","@title":"Holman Rd & Trestle Glen Rd","@lat":"37.8067794","@lon":"-122.2325773","@stopId":"52750"}';
    console.log(str.replace(/@/g,''));

    //will give you
    {"tag":"1013170","title":"Holman Rd & Trestle Glen Rd","lat":"37.8067794","lon":"-122.2325773","stopId":"52750"}
```

By the way your json is valid

```
var json ={"@tag":"1013170","@title":"Holman Rd & Trestle Glen Rd"};

//var json_obj = $.parseJSON(json);//don't do this because it already json.

console.log(json.@tag); // don't use this way

console.log(json['@tag']);// instead try this way
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't change a property name, you have to add the value with a new name and delete the old property:

```
object = {
     "@tag":"1013170",
     "@title":"Holman Rd & Trestle Glen Rd",
     "@lat":"37.8067794",
     "@lon":"-122.2325773",
     "@stopId":"52750"
 }
for (var property in object) {
    if (object.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
        object[property.slice(1)]=object[property];
        delete object[property];
    }
}
console.log(object) will now give you
{tag: "1013170", title: "Holman Rd & Trestle Glen Rd", lat: "37.8067794", lon: "-122.2325773", stopId: "52750"}
```

Comment: I guess the question is: What's the point of doing this in the first place? What the OP posted is syntactically correct, so why do you think that replacing `@` fixes anything?

Comment: @Kaushik Bhat Thank you so much. You saved my time worked like a charme +1

Comment: @Muhammad: I'm curious, what exactly was the problem?

Comment: @FelixKling i had to remove the first place i.e '@', Kaushik answer doing exactly the same.

Comment: @Muhammad: But why did you have to remove it? What exactly are you doing with the data that would cause `@` to be a problem? Because property names can contain *any* character.

Comment: @FelixKling it was causing syntax error (unexpected token illegal) when i read it.

Comment: @Muhammad: Again: The `@` is valid there, so parsing the JSON should work without problems. Kaushik's solution doesn't even consider the parsing step, it builds on top of an already existing object. So, what exactly do you mean by "read it" and what *exactly* are you doing with the data? How are you trying to process it? Please update your question and add the corresponding code. As it stands now, the question is incomplete since it's not possible to reproduce the problem with the given information, and it's far from obvious how this answer actually fixes the "problem".

Comment: @FelixKling sorry Felix Kaushik answer did not work to me, initially it seems that it working but it was not. I post my answer that how i fixed it Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i read the json with this line.

```
result['@tag']
```

Its simple you can read json from '.' notation and from [], the second one reads special character as well.

Comment: See, if you had properly described the problem, and explained that you get an error when you try to do `result.@tag`, then I could have forwarded you to http://stackoverflow.com/q/12953704/218196. Anyways, glad you figured it out. rajesh actually [already provided this as an solution though](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20781257/218196).