# get data from array object in javascript

Tags: javascript, object

I am trying to get data from an object. I have tried to get the data as a.doc._id as given below.

```
function ab(data){alert("content is "+data.doc.id);}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you put the object structure in you question description?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to access object properties containing special characters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953704/how-to-access-object-properties-containing-special-characters)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably need to access the property using the square bracket notation. Try -

```
alert("sdf" + data["doc._id"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

"doc" is not an object, as shown in the inspector, you should rename the property name to something like doc-title instead.

Otherwise, you should create the object something like this

```
var data = {
             "act" : "",
             "doc": {
                 "_id" : "9",
                 "title": "fghfgh"
             }
           };
```