# get json elements with array index in its name

Tags: javascript

Hi I'm trying to get a mongoose error message, and the description has an array index in its name.  This is in a unit test.

```
{message: 'Validation failed',
  name: 'ValidationError',
  errors:
   { 'contactInfo.0.email':
      { message: 'Invalid email',
        name: 'ValidatorError',
        path: 'email',
        type: 'user defined',
        value: 'fjksdal' } },
  key: 'undefined.0.undefined' }
```

previous example to get message i would do this:

```
(err.errors.passHash.message).should.eql('PASSWORD_NOT_HASHED');
```

However variations of this fail and I can see why, not sure what the workaround is.

```
(err.errors.contactInfo.0.email.message).should.eql('Invalid Email')
```

thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to access object properties containing special characters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953704/how-to-access-object-properties-containing-special-characters)

Comment: you are correct Felix, I was improperly asking the question to my ignorance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not valid JSON, so I assume that you mean that it's a Javascript object.

Use bracket syntax to access properties with names that can't be identifiers:

```
(err.errors['contactInfo.0.email'].message).should.eql('Invalid Email')
```