# getting access to javascript object property beginning with number

Tags: javascript, object

I am calling an api which returns an object

```
var rain = data[i].rain;

$.get( "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=London,uk&mode=json&units=metric", function( data ) {
    var data = data.list;
    for(var i = 0; i < 12; i++){
        var rain = data[i].rain;
        console.log(rain)
    }
});
```

rain returns the following when I inspect the console:

```
Object {3h: 0.005}
Object {3h: 0.03}
```

I expected that `rain.3h` would have given me access to 0.005 and 0.03, but it doesn't. I get the following error message : Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Is this because it begins with a number? Can anyone advise how to access this property?

Comment: You can only use dot notation to access properties if the property name is a valid identifier. `'3h'` isn't, so use square bracket notation.

Comment: @RobG so you can always use the bracket notation, but the dot notation only in certain circumstances?

Comment: @PaulFitzgerald: Yes.

Comment: Related: [How to access object properties containing special characters?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12953704/218196)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's because it begins with a number.

You can access that like this:

```
rain['3h']
```

When you have object properties named with numbers or simbols, use the bracket notation.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '3h' of undefined returns this error

Comment: `data[i].rain['3h']` perhaps?

Comment: yes, all good, got it. thanks, will upvote when the time allows me to