# Number as an identifier

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I am currently extracting data from a JSON array that looks like the following

```
    "title": Title,
    "chapters": {
        "13c": {
            "words": 123,
            "spaces": 321
        },
        "15d": {
            "words": 123,
            "spaces": 321
        },
        "38h": {
            "words": 123,
            "spaces": 321
        }
    }
```

The thing is when I try to select 13c (if it exists) with the following

```
if(book.chapters.13c){
     console.log(book.chapters.13c);
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
```

Comment: variable name shouldn't be  started with number. that's why its throwing an error.

Comment: Is there any way to bypass this?

Comment: c13 would be a valid variable name

Comment: Yes, there is a way to bypass this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [getting access to javascript object property beginning with number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30877802/getting-access-to-javascript-object-property-beginning-with-number)

Comment: It does look like a duplicate of that to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For every situation you find yourself unable to use the `.` syntax, use the `[]` syntax instead:

```
console.log(book.chapters['13c']);
```

Note that the `[]` syntax and `.` syntax are equivalent but the `[]` syntax is more flexible since it has no restriction on the attribute key. For example, if your property key contains whitespace:

```
book.chapters['hello world'];
```

if your property key needs to be constructed from variables:

```
book.chapters[somevar + '-' + someothervar];
```

etc.

In javascript, `foo.bar` is just shorthand for `foo['bar']`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
if(book.chapters["13c"]) ...
```

That is functionally equivalent to what you want. Normally you shouldn't use Numbers at the start of an identifier but it is valid. Since it is parsed as a string it is the same.

It is equivalent to creating an object like so:

```
{
  "0":true,
  "1":"testing",
  "2":"yup",
  "length": 3
}
```