# reading data from json file and displaying them on html page

Tags: javascript, json

I have a json file like this :

```
[
 {
 "X_id": [ "id1" ],
"contents.value": [ "AA" ],
"contents.count": [ 95 ] 
},
{
 "X_id": [ "id2" ],
"contents.value": [ "BB" ],
"contents.count": [ 41 ] 
},
{
 "X_id": [ "id3" ],
"contents.value": [ "CC" ],
"contents.count": [ 36 ] 
},
{
 "X_id": [ "id4" ],
"contents.value": [ "DD" ],
"contents.count": [ 4 ] 
},
{
 "X_id": [ "id5" ],
"contents.value": [ "EE" ],
"contents.count": [ 33 ] 
}
]
```

and I want to display this values on my html page, and for the test I try first to show them in console :

```
$.getJSON("example.json", function(data) {})
    .done(function(data) {
       $.each(data.items, function(i, item) {
            console.log(item.contents.value);
        }); 
    })
    .fail(function() {
        console.log("error");
    })
    .always(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
```

but I get this error message :

> TypeError: a is undefined
>
> ...rCase()},each:function(a,c,d){var
>   e,f=0,g=a.length,h=g===b||p.isFunction(a);if(d...

How can I solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Your data is an array of objects. Yet you are trying to pass `data.items` to `$.each`. Arrays don't have such a property:

```
> var data = [];
> data.items
undefined
```

You probably want to pass `data` itself to `$.each`.

See also [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json) .

---

Wrt to `console.log(item.contents.value);` (which is wrong), have a look at [How to access object properties containing special characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12953704/218196) .

Answer (score 0):

Arrays don't have an `items` property. Just use `data` instead:

```
$.getJSON("example.json", function(data) {})
    .done(function(data) {
       $.each(data, function(i, item) {
            console.log(item.contents.value);
        }); 
    })
    .fail(function() {
        console.log("error");
    })
    .always(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

following code working fine check it once , why your getting error because of get json data is array object not so need to pass data[0] then you can iterate ,in key value pairs value is again array.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Consoling Json Array</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>TODO write content</div>
    <script>
        $.getJSON("example.json", function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        })
                .done(function (data) {
                    $.each(data[0], function (i, item) {
                        console.log(i,item[0]);
                    });
                })
                .fail(function () {
                    console.log("error");
                })
                .always(function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                });
    </script>
</body>
```