# How to parse android attributes from JSON converted from XML in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, xml

I am trying to parse `android:versionName` from following JSON object :

```
{
    "android:hardwareAccelerated": "true",
    "android:versionCode": "40020",
    "android:versionName": "4.0.20",
    "package": "com.xxx.xxx",
    "xmlns:android": "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
}
```

can anybody help me in this??

Thank you in advance

Comment: Are you using Javascript or Java ?

Comment: I am using javascript

Comment: @UmaKanth, this is not duplicate of the thread which you are saying. Please check properly while commenting.

Comment: @ChetanPurohit I would suggest you to read the description of the tags properly and then tag them. This is nowhere related to `android` if you just want to parse an object with a android named element in it.

Comment: @Uma Kanth, I am developing hybrid application by using Javascript. So, I guess I should specify Javascript.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access object properties containing special characters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953704/how-to-access-object-properties-containing-special-characters.)

Comment: @UmaKanth, Please check it at yours place. If it works then please comment.

Comment: @ChetanPurohit, have you tried any code yet to achieve what you want? If so, then do post your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use it like this  **Object['key']** -  [Property accessors - Bracket](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation)

for your JSON it will (**Obj** is just a representation of JSON Object):

```
obj['android:versionName']
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have a pure string you need to parse your string to a JSON:

```
var data = JSON.parse(json);
```

Then you can access to property like an object:

```
var androidVersion = data["android:versionName"];
```

---

```js
var jsonObject = JSON.parse('{"android:hardwareAccelerated":"true","android:versionCode":"40020","android:versionName":"4.0.20","package":"com.xxx.xxx","xmlns:android":"http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"}');

document.write(jsonObject['android:versionName']);
```

Comment: In JavaScript it will be `data['android:versionName']`

Comment: Thank you, also if the first comment with `.getString` was wrong :-P However I knew your solution, I had not noticed the colon.

Comment: Please somebody share your ideas about that if you have any.

Comment: I tested it on jsFiddle and it works fine. Try to add [0] between data and ["android:versionName"]. This is a fix in case you have your json in square brakets. Do you have jQuery library?

Comment: Thank you @erikscandola for giving your valuable time and correct solution. :-)