# node.js Count MySQL Query with LIMIT

Tags: javascript

I try to get the number of found rows out of a mysql query with a limitation. Google gave me the hint with the SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS function.

I also get the right result in the "RowDataPackage".

```
RowDataPacket { 'FOUND_ROWS()': 5 }
```

But when i try to parse the result with

```
console.log(rows[0].FOUND_ROWS());
```

I only get the result "undefined". What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access object properties containing special characters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953704/how-to-access-object-properties-containing-special-characters)

Comment: `rows[0].FOUND_ROWS()` is a function call, can you alias your query to return proper column name?

Comment: This is not a node.js question and not a MySQL question. This is a basic JavaScript syntax question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
console.log(rows[0]["FOUND_ROWS()"]);
```

Your current call is being interpreted as a function call.  Instead, use square brackets to escape the key name in your JSON.

As @Tomalak mentioned, your question doesn't have too much to do with MySQL, rather just regular JavaScript.