# how to parse array values inside object

Tags: javascript

```
{ 'notes[]': [ 'book', 'copy', 'pencil', 'eraser' ] }
```

I just want to parse these sets. Please, anyone suggest me some best approach

Comment: You have to provide more context. Is this a string you have that you want to turn into an object? Or do you have an object of that form? What exactly do you want to "parse"? It's certainly not JSON.

Comment: Parse what exactly? This already looks as much like a JavaScript object/array as it will get.

Comment: maybe he want to access the array inside

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using an [invalid identifier](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Variables) as your key (`notes[]`), you will need to use bracket syntax to access:

```js
var data = { 'notes[]': [ 'book', 'copy', 'pencil', 'eraser' ] };
console.log(data['notes[]']);
```

Probably would be better to name the key `notes` instead of `notes[]`. Then you can access with dot notation: `data.notes`

Comment: If that's the OP's problem then it's a [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12953704/218196) and should be closed as such.

Comment: "reserved characters" ?

Comment: @zerkms reserved characters is probably not the correct nomenclature, what I mean by that is: "Characters that cannot be used in a variable, property or function name". `data.notes[]` will not work

Comment: "variable, property or function name" --- or in short, "identifier". So just call it "a not valid identifier"

Comment: Yep, thanks - I will update my answer to be more clear

Comment: Actually sir i am new in node js. I just want to post simple array like ["hello", "world"] from my frontend i.e clientside to server side. I am confused that how to send these array. Sorry for my wrong query.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you want like as below code.

```js
var res = { 'notes': [ 'book', 'copy', 'pencil', 'eraser' ] };
console.log(res.notes[0]); //=> book
console.log(res.notes[1]); //=> copy
console.log(res.notes[2]); //=> pencil
console.log(res.notes[3]); //=> eraser
```