# Special Characters In Vue Template Interpolation syntax?

Tags: templates, vuejs2

I am using an API(MySportsFeeds.com) that returns an object with property names that contain the characters # and @ in them. I get a Vue error message:

```
"- invalid expression: illegal character in _s(item.stats.Wins.@abbreviations) Raw expression: {{ item.stats.Wins.@abbreviations}}
```

when trying to access these object properties.

Here is an example Vue template code snippet:

```
 <div v-for="value in props_league_standings">
            <p class="box-score-team" v-for="item in value.teamentry"> 
               <span class=box-score-team>{{ item.stats.Wins.@abbreviations}}</span>
            </p>
 </div>
```

Does anyone know how I can access these properties with special characters in their names in the Vue template. Thanks in advance

Comment: like `{{ item.stats.Wins['@abbreviations']}}`?

Comment: Wins is not an array. it is an object with a property of @abbreviation

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access object properties containing special characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953704/how-to-access-object-properties-containing-special-characters)

Comment: Im sorry I misunderstood you. Good idea using bracket notation but unfortunately get same error message.

Comment: and to stress it is Vue throwing warning: [Vue warn]: Error compiling template:

Comment: if so, it should be something else caused the problem. check [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gy73tsk2/) which works for one property name with special characters.

Comment: my fault I forgot the parenthesis in bracket notation. It works ok now. good pickup I forgot totally about bracket notation being used. Saved me alotta grief.