# Is there a way to extract the value of an object with key value pairs where the key has a '.'

Tags: javascript, object, javascript-objects

I am trying to store cake prices in an object for different sizes for example:

```
1.5kg = $10 
2kg = $12 
2.5kg = $15 
3kg = $20
```

like

```
let cakePrices = {
   "1.5kg" : "$10",
   "2kg" : "$12",
   "2.5kg" : "$15",
   "3kg" : "$20"
}
```

I know this goes against variable naming convention since a variable name can't start with a number nor can it have a period(.)  
So in what way can I store and retrieve these values?

Comment: [`cakePrices['2.5kg']`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors)

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953704/how-to-access-object-properties-containing-special-characters

Comment: It is also not recommended to store strings that have to be parsed.
Use grammes and assume dollars:
`let cakePricesGrammesInDollar = {
   "1500" : 10,
   "2000" : 12,
   "2500" : 15,
   "3000" : 20
}`

Comment: Thank you @mplungjan I've seen that using "1.5kg" format will cause issues in storing in the database as well