# html table returns NaN data

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

My html table shows NaN value because of field name has a symbol(**/**) in between.

below is my code

```
<tr ng-repeat="user in msg.options | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse | filter:search track by $index" 
       ng-click="msg.payload = user.send(msg);" style="width:100%" flex>
  <td ng-bind="$index+1"></td>
  <td ng-bind="user.PalletID"></td>
  <td ng-bind="user.Description"></td>
  <td ng-bind="user.Location"></td>
  <td ng-bind="user.Empty/NonEmpty"></td>
  <td style="text-align:center" ng-click="msg.payload = user.send(msg);" >
    <img src="http://192.168.137.1:1880/ui/Images/unload32.png" width="30" height="30">
  </td>
     </tr>
```

[image]

Please help to resolve this issue.

Comment: i dont look all the code yet but it will definitly not work as you expect if you put; instead of dot. `user;send(msg)`

Comment: i  have issue with Empty/NonEmpty column. Next image column working fine.

Comment: show the part where you affect the values of user.

Comment: What if you try to:user["Empty/NonEmpty"]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access object properties containing special characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953704/how-to-access-object-properties-containing-special-characters)