# get special labels in a ajax request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm making an AJAX request and I get my object correctly; but there's a problem with some labels, these labels have "-" (*sales-price* i.e.).
So when I want to print in the screen I can't call them properly in my JSX code

```
render(){
    return(
            <div>{
                this.state.products.map((products)=>{
                    return  <div>
                                <p>{productt.id}</p>
                                <p>{productt.name}</p>
                                <p>{productt.sales-price}</p>
                            </div>
                })
            }</div>
            }
        );
}
```

If anyone wants to learn more about the object there's some links that could help:
[JSON example](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YbkAhy40bpb51dYBDjtetzyqq5s1U_4h/view?usp=sharing)
[Documentation about the API I'm using](https://app.stelorder.com/app/indexapi.html)

Comment: `productt["sales-price"]`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I access object properties containing special characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953704/how-can-i-access-object-properties-containing-special-characters)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `{product['sales-price']}` instead of `{product.sales-price}`

```jsx
render() {
    return (
        <div>
        {
            this.state.products.map((product) => (
                <div>
                     <p>{product.id}</p>
                     <p>{product.name}</p>
                     <p>{product['sales-price']}</p>
                </div>
            ))
        }
        </div>
    );
}
```

[More about objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer)

Comment: Where does `productt` come from?

Comment: Author uses this variable

Comment: But it's clearly wrong. And your answer didn't solve the problem by reiterating it.

Comment: With what reiterating? I have already edited my answer, as you can see

Comment: If you're making the same mistake in your answer that the OP is in their code it's not a good answer. Your answer is much better for the edit.

Comment: hi guys, the woandy's solution worked, as the andy's too, thank's a lot. now surges another problems but it's ralationated with the structure of the objec idon't know if you want to help me

Answer (score 0):

You are mapping over an array. The first argument for the `map` callback is the current element (object) of the array you're iterating over, so ideally it should be `product` (singular) rather than `products` (plural). And then you need to access the properties of that object.

If you're returning multiple lines of JSX you should wrap them in parentheses.

Finally, objects which have hyphenate property names need special consideration. You should use bracket notation to access the values.

```
this.state.products.map(product => {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>{product.id}</p>
      <p>{product.name}</p>
      <p>{product['sales-price']}</p>
    </div>
  );
});
```

Comment: hi, it was my error when i typed for the cueston, i use products all the time i'm gonna try your solution