# HTML only posts last text box for text form

Tags: php, html

Here is my HTML code:

```
    <form name="candidates" action="candidate_thankyou.php" method="post">
    <div class="wrap"> 
        <div class="position"> President: <br> </div>
            <input type="text" name="president"> <br>
            <input type="text" name="president"> <br>
            <input type="text" name="president"> <br>
    </div>
    <div class="wrap"> 
        <div class="position"> Vice President: <br> </div>
            <input type="text" name="vp"> <br>
            <input type="text" name="vp"> <br>
            <input type="text" name="vp"> <br>
    </div> ...etc
    <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

However, when I call var_dump($_POST) in my php file, I only get the last text box value for each input name (eg "president" or "vp"). If I only use the first 2 text boxes, I get an empty string. How can I get all three values from the form?

Comment: Show the associated code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Field name must be either unique (`president1`, `president2`, etc.) or an array `president[]`.

Further handling depends on which method you choose. Second method is well described in [HTML form input tag name element array with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3234205/html-form-input-tag-name-element-array-with-javascript)

Answer (score 3):

Form fields are identified by their name. You're overriding the fields `president`/`vp` every time, that's why you only get the last field's values. You can send it as an array like this:

```
<input type="text" name="president[]"> 
<input type="text" name="president[]"> 
..
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have seperate names for each input or add [] to the end of the names to add them to an array. Ie

```
name="vp[]"
```