# Getting a specific field by name?

Tags: jquery

I have a form with a number of fields, each with the same name:

```
<input type="text" name="title[]" placeholder="Title" value="a">
```

How can I get a specific field?

I have tried:

```
console.log($('input[name=title[]]').val());
```

But no luck.

Comment: The question already exists: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3234205/html-form-input-tag-name-element-array-with-javascript

Comment: Not quite @user1852589. The OP is asking how to get the value of a specific element with this name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Adrift [mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24126465/1011527), you need to wrap the name attributes in quotes because it has special character's. Once done you can use `eq()` where you enter the index value of the element to get a specific input element-

```
console.log( $('input[name="title[]"]').eq(3).val() );
```

Answer (score 2):

Wrap the attribute value in quotes since it has a special character (`[` & `]`):

```
console.log($('input[name="title[]"]').val());
```

If you want the value of a specific `input`, use [`.eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) with the target's index as its argument, as @Jay Blanchard [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24126436/getting-a-specific-field-by-name/24126486#24126486):

```
console.log($('input[name="title[]"]').eq(1).val());
```