# How to do name="skills[]" in angularjs in input type text?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In php usually we are doing name="skills[]" to get data from form as array but how to do this in angularjs? 
PHP example:

```
<input type="text" name="skills[]" />
```

I want to do the same in AngularJS but getting syntax error.
I am trying like this:

My code:

```
<input type="text" name="skillname" required data-ng-model="c.skills[].skillname" class="small">
<input type="text" name="skillname" required data-ng-model="c.skills[].skiilname" class="small">
```

Need help. Thanks.

Comment: show the code you tried!

Comment: @Sajeetharan I have edited my question description..

Comment: why downvote before knowing anything?

Comment: what do you want to achieve here? you can just put skillname as ng-model and do a ng-repeat, btw i dint downvote

Comment: Do you have ngRepeat?

Comment: you might find your answer here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3234205/html-form-input-tag-name-element-array-with-javascript]

Comment: no..i dont have ng repeat

Comment: @AhmadMobaraki that is in pure javascript...i want  in pure angularjs way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In angular, data rules your UI, not the other way around. You should have `skills` array in your controller

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.skills = [
    {},
    {},
    {}
  ];
});
```

which you'll feed to `ng-repeat` or something.

```
<div ng-repeat='skill in skills'>
  <input ng-model='skill.name' />
</div>
```

This way, adding new textfields on the page is as easy is pushing a new element to the array, `$scope.skills.push({})`. No need to create DOM elements or anything. This is the angular way.

Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/Uqldnst3gnF07SJGV6Bn?p=preview

Comment: is a way to do this without 'ng-repeat' ? e.g. only two or three inputs

Comment: @AhmadMobaraki: Why not use ng-repeat? I don't see a practical reason. Collection size is not a factor.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

your controller is:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
   $scope.skills = [];
  $scope.formData={
   skillname:[]
      };
  });
```

and your html is:

```
<div ng-repeat="skill in skills">
<input type="text"  required ng-model="formData.skillname[$index]" ng-init="formData.skillname[$index]=skill.skillname" class="small">
  </div>
```

and without ng-repeat you can use this code:

```
<input type="text"  required ng-model="skillname[0]" ng-init="skillname[0]=skills[0].skillname" class="small">
<input type="text" required ng-model="skillname[1]" ng-init="skillname[1]=skills[1].skillname" class="small">
```

Comment: is a way to do this without 'ng-repeat' ? e.g. only two or three inputs

Comment: yes you can.instead of $index you must put number.I'll edit my answer