# Javascript set value for Form obeject Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, forms

I am looking to add data to a form object which is an array.

This works fine:

```
<input type="text" name="object" value="">
<script>document.form.object.value = "value";</script>
```

But when the object is an array it's not working:

```
<input type="text" name="object[]" value="">
<script>document.form.object[0].value = "value";</script>
```

The value of the object is not changing.... Any idea?

I would like to loop the script so I need to create an array. Didn't find any solution...

Comment: you have a typo..., the second example you didn't spell object correctly.

Comment: The DOM API doesn't see `name="aPrice[]"` as array-like. That's PHP (at least) that transform that server-side.

Comment: Sorry. Was an error in this source code. At the source code both names are the same... aka aPrice[].
The error should be found somewhere else

Comment: If you're looping the script, you don't need to make the `name` attribute an array; just create a loop and assign the value the form object each time through, like `document.form.object.value = myArray[i]`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML form input tag name element array with JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3234205/html-form-input-tag-name-element-array-with-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Per [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3234383/1539718), I would utilize `document.form.elements['object[]'].value = "value"`. Otherwise, if you intended on having multiple form elements with the same name (multiple inputs with object[], and iterate via the collection, can use the following:

```
var myForm = document.form;
var myControls = myForm.elements['object[]'];
for (var i = 0; i < myControls.length; i++) {
    var aControl = myControls[i];
}
```

The example provided, in your code, the name provided is not perceived as an array.

Answer (score 0):

The attribute value `"object[]"` is just a string to JavaScript -- it does not interpret that as an array. However, when brackets appear in a name, you cannot use it any more in the dot-notation, but must write:

```js
document.form["object[]"].value = "value";
```

```html
<form name="form">
    <input type="text" name="object[]" value="">
</form>
```

If you have more than one element with `name="object[]"`, then the above will only target the first one of these. To set the value of all those elements, you must loop. This you can (for instance) do with the `elements` property and `Array.from` to iterate over those elements:

```js
Array.from(document.form.elements["object[]"], function(elem) {
    elem.value = "value";
});
```

```html
<form name="form">
    <input type="text" name="object[]" value="">
    <input type="text" name="object[]" value="">
</form>
```

For those using IE: replace `Array.from` with `[].map.call`

Comment: Hurray! Hurray! After 5hours of trying, trial and error: this solution works just fine! Big thank you!!!!

Comment: FYI your 2nd snippet generates an error in IE11: `"Object doesn't support property or method 'from'"`

Comment: IE? That still exists!? :P

Comment: For those using IE (what's wrong with Edge?): replace `Array.from` with `[].map.call`