# Capture Selected Values from Dynamic Drop-down Lists using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to get the value from dynamic drop-down list in my form, but my code isn't working.

View.php

```
<div class="input_fields_wrap">
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-info add_field_button" value="Tambah Cara Pengolahan" /> <br /><br />
</div>
<div class="service-container" data-service=
    "<div class='form-group'>
        <select class='form-control' style='width:88%; display:inline-block; margin-right:10px;' name='cara_pengolahan[]' required>
            <option value=''>No Selected</option>
            <?php foreach($pengolahan as $row):?>
            <option value='<?php echo $row->id_pengolahan;?>'><?php echo $row->cara_pengolahan;?></option>
            <?php endforeach;?>></div>
        </select>
        <button class='btn btn-danger closebtn remove_field'><b>&times</b></button>
    </div>"
</div>
```

Javascript.js

```
$('.service-container').each(function() {
    var container = $(this);
    var service = container.data('service');
    // Service variable now contains the value of html + php variable;  

    var max_fields      = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

    var x = 1; //initlal text box count
    $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
            x++; //text box increment
            $(wrapper).append(service);
        }
    });

    $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent('div').remove();
        x--;
    })
});
var cara_pengolahan = document.forms[0].elements["cara_pengolahan[]"];
if(typeof cara_pengolahan !== 'undefined'){
    for (var i=0; i<cara_pengolahan.length; i++) {
        console.log(cara_pengolahan[i].value);
    }
}
```

When there is one dynamic drop-down list, it returns all the array values of it. But what I want is to capture the selected value of that drop-down list.

[image: Result]

[image: Debug]

And when there are more than one dynamic drop-down lists, it returns the correct selected values of that drop-down lists.

[image: Result]

[image: Debug]

How to capture the selected value of all the dynamic drop-down lists?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can go with `$(".CommanClassyourselectbox").find("option:selected").val();`

Comment: I use array for the name of the html element (drop-down list), so I define ```cara_pengolahan[]``` for that. And I've tried your suggestion, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
myval= $("#id").find("option:selected").val();
```

Where #id is the id of your select input

Comment: inspect the html page to ensure you've got the right id (you have to replace #id with #your_id

Comment: cara_pengolahan[] doest seems a valid id for an html element.  Why are you using brakets in the id ?

Comment: Sorry, I mean, I use array for the name of the html element (drop-down list), so I define ```cara_pengolahan[]``` for that. The brackets indicate that the value of such drop-down list will be posted as an array, so another drop-down list means just another value in existing array. You can see my code and the result from my code above. And I've tried your suggestion, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

To check if there is a dynamic Drop down you can simple check if the selector exists
with

```js
 $('#elemId').length>0
```

And for selected value you can use $("#selectorid").find("option:selected").val();

Comment: I use array for the name of the html element (drop-down list), so I define ```cara_pengolahan[]``` for that like my code above. So, your suggestion is not working.